# Coffee machine question

Tags: discussion

I have a high end but not commercial latte machine

It has broken three time and twice I was able to fix it and third I had to pay.

It is broken again but since it is getting old I am reluctant to pay as it will be $130 minimum and no guarantee they can fix it.

Is a coffee machine repair on scope for this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that coffee machine repair is a facet of producing and consuming coffee and therefore is acceptable as per the guidelines on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Coffee Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in all aspects of producing and consuming coffee.